# JAXB : How to add attributes to an inner element

Tags: java, attributes, annotations, jaxb, java-6

I have the below XML that I want to read. Using JAXB on java 1.6, how do I annotate for the attribute regex ? Can I have the field to be of type boolean ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <authStore>
  <authList>
       <auth>
         <resource>res1</resource>
         <privilege regex = "true">PRIV_FILE_.+?_READ</privilege>   
       </auth>
       <auth>
         <resource>res2</resource>
         <privilege>PRIV_FILE_READ</privilege>   
       </auth>
</authStore>
```

UPDATE : Is it possible to make the attribute optional ? If yes, when I unmarshal, will I get regex field to be false when a privilege element does not have the optional attribute regex ?

UDPATE2 : I don't want to define separate classes for resource and privilege. Also, I don't want to use MOXy. Pls. suggest solution for sun/oracle JDK 1.6 JAXB only.

UPDATE3 : My current object model is something like this

```
// AuthStore.java
@XmlRootElement
public class AuthStore {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "authList")
    @XmlElement(name = "auth")
    private ArrayList<Auth> authList;

    public void setAuthList(ArrayList<Auth> authList) {
        this.authList = authList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Auth> getAuthsList() {
        return authList;
    }
}


// Auth.java    
@XmlRootElement(name = "auth")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "resource", "privilege" })
public class Auth
{
    private String resource;
    private String privilege;

    @XmlElement(name = "resource")
    public String getResource()
    {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(String resource)
    {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "privilege")
    public String getPrivilege()
    {
        return privilege;
    }

    public void setPrivilege(String author)
    {
        this.privilege = author;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want your object model to look like?

Comment: thanks. added current model. I have the stuff working. Except now I want to add the optional attribute "regex".

Comment: Is the value of `regex` always `true` or can it change?

Comment: regex value can be false also. think of it like this => Tomorrow, I can rename "regex" to "type" and have various values. example type="regex" or type = "expression", etc. Am I clear ?

Comment: Yes, @SamiKorhonen has posted the correct solution for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because privilege contains an attribute (It's actually complex type), you must create a class to hold both the value and the attribute:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement(name = "authStore")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccesssType.FIELD)
public class AuthStore {
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = AuthStore.class.getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AuthStore.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        AuthStore authStore = (AuthStore)unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);

        System.out.println(authStore.getAuthList().get(0).getResource());
        System.out.println(authStore.getAuthList().get(0).getPrivilege().getRegex());
        System.out.println(authStore.getAuthList().get(0).getPrivilege().getValue());
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "authList")
    @XmlElement(name = "auth")
    private List<Auth> authList;

    public List<Auth> getAuthList() {
        return authList;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccesssType.FIELD)
    public static class Auth {
        @XmlElement(name = "resource")
        private String resource;
        @XmlElement(name = "privilege")
        private Privilege privilege;

        public String getResource() {
            return resource;
        }

        public Privilege getPrivilege() {
            return privilege;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccesssType.FIELD)
            public static class Privilege {
            @XmlAttribute(name = "regex")
            private Boolean regex;
            @XmlValue
            private String value;

            public Boolean getRegex() {
                return regex;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - I would recommend annotation the get methods, or setting `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccesssType.FIELD)`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: While I don't think annotating the get methods would work without creating setters, which often are obsolete (e.g. when reading a configuration file or some other immutable data object), I agree, that @XmlAccessType should be set.

Comment: thank you. I selected this as answer without trying since Blaise Doughan recommended. I will try and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: The OP had set methods, I didn't want them to try your solution and hit a duplicate property exception.  You are correct if there are only getters then there will be no conflict.